# how can I join two queries in which one is derived from other?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Could somebody explain me whats wrong in this? My query is like this...

```
select t1.year, t1.empid, t2.tcost
from (select year,empid,sum(cost) as total from orders group by year,empid) t1
inner join (select year, max(total) from t1 group by year) t2
on t1.year= t2.year
```

I am getting error message as below

```
ERROR at line 3:

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I know I can achieve this using WITH clause but I want to know how to use join in this case.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in your query you use self-join, there is usually an equivalent query based on analytical functions. 
The advantage is, in most cases, shorter execution time. Here you could use [`max ... keep dense rank ...`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm):

```
select year, empid, sum_cost 
  from (
    select year, empid, sum(cost) sum_cost,
           max(sum(cost)) keep (dense_rank last order by sum(cost)) 
                          over (partition by year) max_cost
      from orders group by year, empid )
  where sum_cost = max_cost
```

Sample data and output:

```
create table orders (year number(4), empid number(5), cost number(10,2));
insert into orders values (2010, 1, 100);
insert into orders values (2010, 1, 115);
insert into orders values (2010, 1, 207);
insert into orders values (2010, 2, 104);
insert into orders values (2011, 1,  90);
insert into orders values (2011, 2,  15);
insert into orders values (2011, 2, 107);
insert into orders values (2011, 3, 100);
```

Output:

```
YEAR  EMPID  SUM_COST
----  -----  --------
2010      1       422
2011      2       122
```

---

**Edit:** I doubt you could eliminate `with` clause if you want to do self-join here. `with` is used especially when complex sub-queries are used twice or more.
And if you insist on `join` instead of `where (year,tcost) in ...`, as you suggested in of the comments, please use:

```
with vvn as (select year, empid, sum(cost) as sc from orders group by year, empid) 
  select v1.year, v1.empid, v1.sc from vvn v1
    join (select year, max(sc) msc from vvn group by year) v2 
      on v1.year = v2.year and v1.sc = v2.msc;
```

BTW, shortened version of my first answer does not really need `keep dense rank` part, simpler is:

```
select year, empid, sum_cost 
  from (select year, empid, sum(cost) sum_cost,
               max(sum(cost)) over (partition by year) max_cost
          from orders group by year, empid )
  where sum_cost = max_cost
```

Version with somehwat modified `keep...` is still valid and interesting, but you probably noticed this.

Comment: This is one way using analytical functions....is it possible to get the same result using any type of join? we should use JOIN keyword...

Comment: Answer updated. Hope this closes topic or gives full clues. If not - Is this a homework? First and only answer is to use analytical function - here sum and max. If your teacher wants to join answer with something - 
join with dual on 1=1. But, as per my experience teachers are right. Please provide full question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.year, t1.empid, t2.tcost
FROM (SELECT year, empid, sum(cost) AS total
      FROM orders
      GROUP BY year, empid) t1
     INNER JOIN (SELECT year, max(total) **AS tcost**
                 FROM t1 **<-- ?? No, you need to specify a table**
                 GROUP BY year) t2
         ON t1.year = t2.year
```

You have a comma between t1 and INNER, and syntax is wrong in FROM T1, you cannot JOIN an inner table to another inner. Also max(total) needs to be aliased. All shown above.

Comment: by mistake i put comma...i have removed now.....so is it not possible to use temp table name in another temp table? like mentioning t1 in t2. Please suggest if there is other way ...but i do not want to repeat entire code of t1 in t2...

Comment: `WITH vvn as (select year,empid,sum(cost) as tcost from vivek group by year, empid)
select year,empid,tcost from vvn
where (year,tcost) in ( select year, max(tcost) from vvn group by year)
order by year;`.....this is the actual query...here i am trying to achieve the same result using join and eliminate WITH clause...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t.year, t.empid, t.total
from (select t1.year,t1.empid,sum(t1.cost) as total from orders as t1  
inner join orders as t2 on t1.year= t2.year  group by t1.year,t1.empid) t
```

[SQL JOINing a Table to Itself](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/sql-joining-a-table-to-itself)

Comment: Its not working ...showing error message as below....                                                                                                    from (select t1.year,t1.empid,sum(t1.cost) as total from orders as t1
                                                               *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: its working if we remove "as" before t1 and t2 in the query. BTB I am using Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0....

Comment: so, what is your requirement,you didn't mentioned in question. Your question is 'Could somebody explain me whats wrong in this?'

Comment: let me explain my requirement.... there is a table called orders(orderid, year, empid, cost)...now i want to display who made highest billing in each year.... first i am finding total amount for each employee in each year using this query `select year,empid,sum(cost) as total from orders group by year,empid)`...next i am finding max amount for each year using this query `select year, max(total) from t1 group by year` ...here t1 is nothing but above query only....instead of repeating query again I used it as a temp table and joining both to fetch empid... here comes the problem...

Comment: try `select year,max(total) from (select year,empid,sum(cost) as total from orders group by year,empid) as sub_qry group by year`

Comment: `select year,empid,sum(cost) as total from orders group by year,empid`...this is t1
`select year, max(total) from t1 group by year` .....this is t2.....actually t2 is subset of t1 only....instead of repeating entire code i simply mentioned it as t1 in t2 and joined both tables...when executing this query its showing error message as t1 not exist....so how to mention table name without repeating entire code in the place t1 in t2